# Dynamic form with multi select option box option

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-select2

I have this dynamic form that lets me add more form inputs if user selects the + button or remove it if they select the - button. In this form I have a drop down selector I wanted to take this selector and make it so the user can select multiple options in the select box. I have included the select2 API however I am not able to select multiple options. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

```js
var room = 1;
function education_fields() {
 
    room++;
    var objTo = document.getElementById('education_fields')
    var divtest = document.createElement("div");
  divtest.setAttribute("class", "form-group removeclass"+room);
  var rdiv = 'removeclass'+room;
    divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Schoolname" name="Schoolname[]" value="" placeholder="School name"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" name="Major[]" value="" placeholder="Major"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Degree" name="Degree[]" value="" placeholder="Degree"></div></div><div class="col-sm-3 nopadding"><div class="form-group"><div class="input-group"> <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]"><option value="">Date</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option> </select><div class="input-group-btn"> <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_education_fields('+ room +');"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button></div></div></div></div><div class="clear"></div>';
    
    objTo.appendChild(divtest)
}
   function remove_education_fields(rid) {
     $('.removeclass'+rid).remove();
   }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">

    <title>Dynamic Form Fields - Add &amp; Remove Multiple fields - Bootsnipp.com</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- select2 boxes-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>


</head>


<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Dynamic Form Fields - Add & Remove Multiple fields</div>
  <div class="panel-heading">Education Experience</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  
  <div id="education_fields">
          
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Schoolname" name="Schoolname[]" value="" placeholder="School name">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Major" name="Major[]" value="" placeholder="Major">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Degree" name="Degree[]" value="" placeholder="Degree">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]">
        <option value="">Date</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="education_fields();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Next</button>
<div class="clear"></div>
  
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer"><small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></span> to add another form field :)</small>, <small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus gs"></span> to remove form field :)</small></div>
  
</div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    // select2 place holder text
    $('#educationDate').select2({
    placeholder: 'Pick An Option'
    });
</script>
```

[image: how to fix the selected options]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 adopts to standard HTML attributes.

https://select2.org/configuration/options-api

You need to add multiple to your select

```
<select multiple
```

Comment: Thanks..And dang I actually knew that. One other question if you know. Now the select two works ass I added `multiple="multiple"` in my select tag. But now when I click the add button the options selected seem to be lost.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the form after adding the multiple attribute. also you can see the output in my running code example.

Comment: Since select2 applies to matching selects when its called, the browser doesn't know you want to turn the dynamic selects to select2. So at the end of your add function, simply recall the select2 function. There are other things you can do to improve your code like not mixing plain javascript with jQuery but that won't fix any of the problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Thank you for that comment. Is there any example you can share on that? I am very new to javascript and I tried what you said to recall the select2 function but I got very awkward behavior.